# Alfresco permissions depending on whether document is currently part of workflow or not

Tags: permissions, alfresco, activiti

Out-of-the-box, an Alfresco user can read a document based on:

- The document's permissions
- The user's role
- The user's groups
- Whether the user owns the document or not
- Maybe some other factors I forgot?

Now, I want to add a new factor: **Whether the document is currently part of a workflow**.

Alfresco's `permissionDefinitions.xml` allows me to define permissions based on `authorities` such as `ROLE_LOCK_OWNER` etc, but it does not seem to be the right place to add permission conditions.

I guess I will have to write some Java source code, but I am not sure what classes are responsible for this, and whether there is an *Alfresco way* to customize them?

Comment: What about updating document's aspect (depending on workflow) and using aspect based permission? http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/secur-permissions.html

Comment: @imagine: Great idea! Would you mind writing an answer with a bit more details? For instance a `permissionModelExtension.xml` sample and relevant `sitePermissionDefinitions.xml` maybe? I will look up what "aspect-based permissions" are.

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul please check this  link may be you will get what you want.. https://community.alfresco.com/thread/209619-how-to-check-if-document-has-workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I assume you want to somehow have nodes that are attached to a workflow have different access rights? You need to think about the behavior you want in all of the UIs and protocols you are exposing (e.g. share, WebDAV, CIFS, FTP, etc.).

If you want to set a permission on a node, you can do that via JavaScript as well as Java (See http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/API-JS-setPermission.html and http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-services-permission.html). As was mentioned in one of the comments, you can also get the number of active workflows on a node by referencing the activeWorkflows property in JavaScript (http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/API-JS-ScriptNode.html) or in Java

Depending on the specifics, I might implement this in different ways, but if all you want to do is have the permission change, you could just update it at the beginning and end of your workflow with a simple javascript call. The only thing bad about that is that it doesn't take into consideration the workflow getting canceled. You could also create a policy/behavior on an aspect you attach or even have a rule or job run that updates content based on the activeWorkflows values.